# Knowing when external process is done writing a file

Tags: c++, qt

My program (C++, Qt5) is calling a command line program in a `QProcess` to perform some curve fitting. Once started, the external program performs several least-squares iterations. After each iteration, it writes an output file that I want to read and display in my GUI program. It typically runs 10-100 iterations until the fit converges and the process terminates. One iteration takes anywhere between **0.1** and **1** second. My GUI program reacts to the signal `QProcess::readyRead()` and reads the output file generated by the external program. In theory, this works because the external process generates some text output on stdout after each iteration.

My problem, however, is that very often the output file is still being written to by the external program (or buffered by the OS) or already opened for the next iteration. The GUI program can read it, it is not locked, but it is incomplete. I spent a lot of time adding a delay after receiving the `readyRead()` signal and optimizing it on the fly to determine the time between after the file is closed and before it is opened again by the external process. But that was not reliable, as the delay strongly depends on hardware and file size, and Qt signals don't arrive in real-time.

Is there any better approach that works on Windows, Linux, and macOS? I would prefer to keep platform-dependent code at a minimum, but at the moment I'm totally stuck and I don't even know in which direction to search for a solution. For information, my GUI program is written in C++ / Qt5 and licensed under GPL v2 or later.

Comment: [QProcess::finished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) doesn't help?

Comment: OS buffering shouldn't be an issue. If another process opens the same file and reads beyond what's actually written to disk it should be getting data from the buffers. So the external program only needs to synchronize when itself has finished writing.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I need to capture the output while the process is running to display the progress of the curve fit. When it emits ::finished(), it's too late.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. Good to know. Maybe the real problem is the timing of the QProcess::readyRead() signal.

Comment: Based on the abstract information you provided, it is not possible to reliably sync your GUI program and the external program. So, your best option is probably to deal with the async nature of your problem. Does the external program use a separate file for each iteration? Does the external program overwrite the output of the previous iteration? Aren't you able to just parse the complete iterations and skip the incomplete one?

Comment: @m7913d It overwrites the same file after each iteration. I am currently ignoring the incomplete files with the "adapting read delay" method. But in some cases almost all are incomplete and there is no GUI update for most of the process.

Comment: Does the external program support some option to create separate files for each iteration? It's somewhat strange to write output to a file and overwrite it less than a second later. Have you tried to read the file constantly, even before the `QProcess::readyRead` signal is emitted?

Comment: @m7913d It does not support separate output files for each iteration. In my latest attempt I am using a QTimer firing every 10 ms to poll the file size, and as soon as it is constant, I am reading the file. But even though it is constant, the content is often incomplete when I parse the file. That is why I suspected that buffering is causing problems.

Comment: doesn't the external process write some info about the progress to stdout? maybe there is some command line switch which can tell it to output info about progress of writing to files (ften it is something like -v = verbose). in that case you could parse stdout and know which files are finished and ready to be read.

Comment: Open in exclusive mode hekps? wait for process exit?or watch the file for any edits and update UI?